# How do I select a row by a condition met in another row in R?

Tags: r

Thank you in advance for your help! I've been smashing my head against my keyboard with this one...

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
Color  <- c("blue","blue","blue","red","red","red","red","green","green")
Age <- c(55, 54, 52, 55, 54, 52, 55, 53, 52)
Lab <- c("A1c", "A1c", "Cre", "Cre", "A1c" , "A1c", "A1c", "A1c", "Cre")

group <- data.frame(Color, Lab, Age)
```

```
 Color Lab Age
1  blue A1c  55
2  blue A1c  54
3  blue Cre  52
4   red Cre  55
5   red A1c  54
6   red A1c  52
7   red A1c  55
8 green A1c  53
9 green Cre  52
```

For each **Color**, I would like to select all **A1cs** for which **Age** is within 1 year of **Cre** (for that same **Color**). I hope to end up with a table like this:

```
Color Lab Age
1  blue Cre  52
2   red Cre  55
3   red A1c  54
4   red A1c  55
5 green A1c  53
6 green Cre  52
```

I would like to keep all **Cre** regardless of whether or not an **A1c** meets my criteria.

Comment: Why is the 1st row `blue Cre  52` selected?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - I would like to keep all "Cre" regardless of whether or not an "A1c" meets my criteria.

Answer (score 0):

For each `Color` you can select rows where the absolute difference in `Age` between `'A1c'` and `'Cre'` is less than equal to 1.

```
library(dplyr)

group %>%
  group_by(Color) %>%
  filter(abs(Age - Age[Lab == 'Cre']) <= 1)

#  Color Lab     Age
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 blue  Cre      52
#2 red   Cre      55
#3 red   A1c      54
#4 red   A1c      55
#5 green A1c      53
#6 green Cre      52
```

Comment: Thank you! So much simpler than I thought it would be! (I'm relatively new at coding, I really appreciate the help!)